# Augmented Reality with iPhone question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, augmented-reality

I'm currently reading this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/jonmarimba/203-is-it-real-or-is-it-virtual-augmented-reality-on-the-iphone) about Augmented Reality and I'm asking myself why the coder are setting the x coordinate of the overlay element to 160-497.8*sin(relDirection). Look at slide 25 for more details. I understand the mathematic background about the geo calculation but how do you know the number 497.8 ? I think there is a logical background and I cant see it.

```
CGPoint overlayCenter = [overlayGraphicView center];
overlayCenter.y = 240.0 - 537.8 * sin(relativeVertAngleToMarriott);
overlayCenter.x = 160.0 - 497.8 * sin(relativeDirectionToMarriott);
[overlayGraphicView setCenter:overlayCenter];
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a field vision of 37.5 so you need 360/37.5 = 9.6 iPhone screens to make a 360 panoramic photo. Given that each screen has 320 pixels width that makes 3072 pixels. 3072/2*Pi = 495 pixels

To be honest, I have no idea what I'm talking about, I just kinda put all numbers on the mixer and found a match.

Comment: I wrote a sample project to test this assumption (https://github.com/j4n0/AR) and it seems correct. He was basically calculating the pixels per degree based on the field vision, and then reposition the object in the screen according to the difference between his heading and the angle to the object location.

Comment: hey @jano, I checked your source, good job. Thank you for code comments also.